# How to reduce the opacity of an UIButton gradually?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uianimation

In my project i have an UIButton which on clicking zooms. Everything is fine till here but i require the opacity of the button to gradually decrease from 1 to 0. I mean it should decrease in 1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.0 sequence. My current code is

```
    -(void)roundButtonAnimation
{
    self.buttonZoom = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    self.buttonZoom.duration = 0.8f;
    self.buttonZoom.values = @[[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(2,2,2)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(3,3,3)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(5,5,5)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(6,6,6)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(7,7,7)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(9,9,9)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(10,10,10)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(11,11,11)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(12,12,12)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(13,13,13)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(14,14,14)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(15,15,15)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(16,16,16)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(17,17,17)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(18,18,18)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(50,50,50)]];
    self.buttonZoom.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    self.roundButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0);
    self.roundButton.alpha = 0.3;
    [self.roundButton.layer addAnimation:self.buttonZoom forKey:@"buttonScale"];

[self.CLSpinnerView1 stopAnimating];
    //[self performSelector:@selector(secondView) withObject:self afterDelay:0.3];

    [self performSelector:@selector(postNotification) withObject:self afterDelay:0.6];
}
```

Comment: What produces this code ? What's the matter?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why aren't you using simple transform  and alpha animations using curve linear?

Comment: @Andrea simple transform and alpha animations curve linear... Is it possible to zoom with this code??

Comment: @Ilario This code zooms the button

Comment: Try two CAAnimations, one for zooming and the other for alpha (opacity) then add them to CAAnimationGroup and assign that group to your button/method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         self.roundButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(50.0f, 50.0f);
                         self.roundButton.alpha = 0.0;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];
}
```

Let's explain a little, in this animation block you say that the animation should take place in one second, during this second based on a linear curve (thus always equal increment/decrement) the button should zoom 50 times and alpha should be animate to 0.

I do not understand why you are using a more complicated `CAKeyframeAnimation` over that simple animation block.

Keyframe animation are useful when you want more power over timings and animate over a set of values.

Answer (score 1):

`UIView animateWithDuration:animations:` should serve your purpose here.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    button.alpha = 0.0;
}];
```

Will gradually change the button's alpha to 0 over one second (`...WithDuration:1.0...`).

See the [The `UIView` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108) for more information.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[button.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"opacity"];
```